# Kubelet is not working as a service in windows(How to start the kubelet as a service)

Tags: devops

Start-Service kubelet
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'kubelet (kubelet)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service kubelet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: I have created the service but its not running

Comment: Through the service i am getting error "windows could not start the kubelet service on local computer"

Comment: Hey Amol, did you solve this?